# SSRS and excel functions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an Excel spreadsheet I use as a dataset in SSRS using the following "SQL":

```
Select Distinct [Business Owner] as BusinessOwner
From [Completed Change Requests$]
Order by [Business Owner]
```

What I want is to add an ID column so my results would look like this:

```
ID    | Business Owner
1     | Owner 1
2     | Owner 2
```

Can I do this directly, or is there some form of shenanigans I can concoct that will net me the results I want?

Comment: Maybe this:   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159225%28v=sql.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Only trouble is, one can't use RowNumber in a calculated field in SSRS.

Comment: You would use RowNumber in your table not a Calculated field.

Comment: And how would I use RowNumber?  I can't put it in the query as the ODBC excel driver doesn't like it, and I can't put it in a calculated field because SSRS doesn't like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RowNumber in the tablix column expression by giving the dataset name or group name as scope. 
For example:

```
    =RowNumber("DatasetName/GroupName")
```